# add songs from array to queue one by one

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, spotify

So I am new to javascript and am wondering how I can extract every song in a spotify playlist, then put them into the queue.

Currently I have this code:

```
// Search for the playlist using the discord-player
            let url = interaction.options.getString("url") // The url of the spotify playlist

            const tracks = getTracks(url); //returns an array containing the first 100 songs in a playlist
            console.log(tracks);

            async function getResults(track){
                const result = await client.player.search(track, {
                    requestedBy: interaction.user,
                    searchEngine: QueryType.AUTO
                })
                if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                    return interaction.reply(`No playlists found with ${url}`)

                await queue.addTracks(result.track) //Adds the track to the queue
            }

            tracks.forEach(getResults(tracks)); // (should) run the function for every single song
```

This code doesn't work though and I wonder how do I do this?

Comment: `getResults()` expects an argument whose parameter is named `track` -> singular. But you're calling it with `tracks` -> plural. That should already raise an alert ;)

Comment: Explaine of Andreas comment: `tracks.forEach(track => getResults(track));`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini `.forEach(getResults)` does the same

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I tried that, but it gives me the this error:
`
TypeError: query.includes is not a function
    at Function.resolve (E:\DiscordMusicBotUwU\node_modules\discord-player\dist\utils\QueryResolver.js:32:79)
    at getResults (E:\DiscordMusicBotUwU\commands\play.js:106:52)
    at E:\DiscordMusicBotUwU\commands\play.js:117:43
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.execute (E:\DiscordMusicBotUwU\commands\play.js:117:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (E:\DiscordMusicBotUwU\index.js:62:9)
`